# Installaton of mongodb on 20.04 ubuntu is new headache

Tags: mongodb

i get some kinda of error just by 
sudo apt-get update
[This image shows about the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfnWJ.png)

Comment: Instead of taking a screenshot, can you copy the terminal output and out them in a code block (between three ``` before and after)?

Comment: Also, can you please change your title to be a little more precise (many errors cause headaches ;) )